# Cannot add records to Access linked table via query, but can update and delete via query and add directly to the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, linked-tables

I have an Access front end for a SQL database. I can add, update and delete records directly in the tables from Access. I can also update and delete rows from queries based on those tables. However, I am unable to add records to any queries. They can be simple queries based on one table with no criteria, it doesn't matter. I am unable to add rows.

I am the db owner, by the way, so permissions should not be a problem. Also, like I said, I can add directly to the tables, just not through queries.

Have any of you experienced this behavior?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: It would help if you could post an example of one of your queries and one of your tables.

Comment: Thank you! In the process of running through it again to post here, I noticed that I can add rows to the queries, but only if the primary key is included in the select statement. I was not aware of that requirement.

Comment: Yes. That is your answer. The PK column must be part of the query. Otherwise, the DB can't be sure that it is ONLY updating/deleting the intended row. You would think that it doesn't matter for Insert, but when doing an insert it needs to make sure it is not inserting conflicting rows (only when inserting into a query)